# RP 3b - green led flashes 4 times

Tags: boot, sd-card, led

I tested one SD card on 2 different RPis and I get the same pattern: no boot, green led blinks continuously on a 4-blink pattern. This would point to a problem with the SD card but I tried reading the card on my linux box and it worked fine. However, I do see some files on the root partition named **FSCK0*.REC** which would make me think there's a FS problem? But, again, no problem mounting the partitions.... even tried running a fsck on the second partition, just in case.

Other than those files, these are the other files present on the FS:

`bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
BCM271~2.DTB
bootcode.bin
cmdline.txt
config.txt
fixup_cd.dat
fixup.dat
fixup_db.dat
fixup_x.dat
kernel7.img
kernel.img
LICENSE.oracle
start_cd.elf
start_db.elf
start_x.elf`

I just checked on a TV set and I get no video output at all from it.

Comment: What OS? If it **IS** a 3B you are missing something.

Comment: you mean, not enough files? then i think it's better to recreate a new image and replace the linux image with the one from the current sd card (or only my project files... will think about it).

Comment: The `overlays/` directory is missing.

Comment: according to documentation: 4 flashes = start.elf not launched - as there is no start.elf in your list, I'd say that's a fairly good indication of the problem - although, 3 flahses, start.elf not found would seem more appropriate